# Curl image download access denied

Tags: curl

Trying to grab this image using curl and getting access denied:

http://g.nordstromimage.com/imagegallery/store/product/Medium/0/_8666540.jpg

Below is the command and response:

```
$ curl -o -v out.jpg http://g.nordstromimage.com/imagegallery/store/product/Medium/0/_8666540.jpg
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   950    0   950    0     0  10288      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 10326
<HTML><HEAD>
<TITLE>Access Denied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>Access Denied</H1>

You don't have permission to access "http&#58;&#47;&#47;g&#46;nordstromimage&#46;com&#47;imagegallery&#47;store&#47;product&#47;Medium&#47;0&#47;&#95;8666540&#46;jpg" on this server.<P>
Reference&#32;&#35;18&#46;1783183e&#46;1393076051&#46;4095e5e
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now the `out.jpg` is considered as the host name. Output file name should come just right after the `-o` parameter.

Also add the user-agent string with your command through `-A` parameter.

This should work for you.

`curl -v -o out.jpg -A "Mozilla" http://g.nordstromimage.com/imagegallery/store/product/Medium/0/_8666540.jpg`